# Adaptar JFrame y componentes a tamaño de pantalla

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un pequeño problema... actualmente estoy con Java ( Netbeans) y necesito que el panel se adapte a cualquier pantalla y no he podido lograrlo.. he intentado con Layouts, pero no creo que esté funcionando...

ASI SE VE DE LA MANERA "NORMAL" SIN MAXIMIZAR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y CUANDO MAXIMIZO LA PANTALLA QUEDA DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -2):

Yo lo eh realizado en C#, pero no funciona solamente habilitando funciones. Debes de realizar algo como esto:

```
        int LX, LY,SW,SH;
    private void iconmaximizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LX = this.Location.X;
            LY = this.Location.Y;
            SW = this.Size.Width;
            SH = this.Size.Height;
            this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
            this.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
            iconmaximizar.Visible = false;
            iconrestaurar.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Esto esta desarrollado en C#, es muy similar en JAVA.

Comment: y eso te modifica todo los componentes, o hay que hacerlo componente por componente?

Comment: Comentabas que ya habías probado con **Layout**, ahora nada más configura el **Anchor, Dock y algunos otros** y debería de funcionar. Acá podes encontrar ejemplos ya realizados sobre ello: [enlace](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f45/que-maximicen-componentes-maximizar-ventana-983577/) espero te ayude.